# I need help understanding the applications of basic axioms and propostions in a probability question

Tags: probability

J is taking 2 books along on her holiday vacation. With Probability .5 she will like the first book. With probability .4 she will like the second book. With probability .3 she will like both books. What is the probability that she likes neither book?

The book gives:

$P(B_1 U B_2)= P(B_1)+P(B_2)-P(B_1 B_2)$ is the probability she likes at least one book.

How does it follow that $P(B_1 U B_2)$ equals what I listed above.

Answer (score 1):

This is [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#In_probability). If you draw a venn diagram of two circles representing the events $B_1$ and $B_2$, you can see how the formula arises.

Answer (score 0):

One of the probability axioms is that when $A\cap B=\emptyset$ one has $Pr(A\cup B)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)$

Note now that

- $B_1 = (B_1\setminus B_2)\cup (B_1\cap B_2)$
- $B_2 = (B_2\setminus B_1)\cup (B_1\cap B_2)$
- $B_1\cup B_2 = (B_1\setminus B_2)\cup (B_1\cap B_2)\cup (B_2\setminus B_1)$
- All of $(B_1\setminus B_2), (B_2\setminus B_1)$ and $(B_1\cap B_2)$ are mutually disjoint.

From the axiom mentioned in the first line, it follows that

- $Pr(B_1)=Pr(B_1\setminus B_2)+Pr(B_1\cap B_2)$
- $Pr(B_2) = Pr(B_2\setminus B_1)+ Pr(B_1\cap B_2)$
- $Pr(B_1\cup B_2) = Pr(B_1\setminus B_2)+ Pr(B_1\cap B_2)+Pr(B_2\setminus B_1)$

Adding and subtracting $Pr(B_1\cap B_2)$ to the final line (*which is a fancy way of adding zero which doesn't change anything*) and using the previous two lines, we get then what is referred to as the principle of inclusion-exclusion for two sets, namely

$Pr(B_1\cup B_2)=Pr(B_1)+Pr(B_2)-Pr(B_1\cap B_2)$

---

One can extend this inductively to any number of sets/events.  The four set case for example would look like

$Pr(A\cup B\cup C\cup D)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)+Pr(C)+Pr(D)\\~~~~-Pr(A\cap B)-Pr(A\cap C)-Pr(A\cap D)-Pr(B\cap C)-Pr(B\cap D)-Pr(C\cap D)\\~~~~ + Pr(A\cap B\cap C)+Pr(A\cap B\cap D)+Pr(A\cap C\cap D)+Pr(B\cap C\cap D)-Pr(A\cap B\cap C\cap D)$